# Xcode doesn't compile with gtest framework, however sees it

Tags: c++, xcode, googletest

I have downloaded, compiled the project with gtest. Then I put **gtest.framework** in **/Library/Frameworks**. So, IDE highlight code correctly:
[code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grHF6.jpg)

But when compiling this error appears:

> ld: library not found for -lgtest_main
>
> clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> Ld /Users/Me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gtests-fgfrckirrlestcgfahvvtwdhgndr/Build/Products/Debug/gtests normal x86_64
>       cd /Users/Me/Desktop/Study/Projects/gtests
>       export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.10
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -L/Users/Me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gtests-fgfrckirrlestcgfahvvtwdhgndr/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/Me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gtests-fgfrckirrlestcgfahvvtwdhgndr/Build/Products/Debug -F/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/Me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gtests-fgfrckirrlestcgfahvvtwdhgndr/Build/Intermediates/gtests.build/Debug/gtests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/gtests.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.10 -stdlib=libc++ -lgtest_main -framework gtest -lgtest -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gtests-fgfrckirrlestcgfahvvtwdhgndr/Build/Intermediates/gtests.build/Debug/gtests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/gtests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gtests-fgfrckirrlestcgfahvvtwdhgndr/Build/Products/Debug/gtests

I guess, framework does contain only headers files and I also have to add **libgtest_main.a** and **libgtest.a** into some directory, but I haven't found any appropriate folder. What do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Linker Search Paths of the project for both your debug and release builds.

You can set to be something like: `$(PROJECT_DIR)/Library/Frameworks`

Use the `$(PROJECT_DIR)` to align your search paths instead of just including a static path.

Comment: I haven't got it. My project directory doesn't contain Library/Frameworks. Anyway I just wrote those notes to LinkerSearchPath, made this folders, added .framework and .a -files there. Thus, I got another error:
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "testing::internal::EqFailure(char const* ... td::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool)", referenced from:
      testing::AssertionResult ... in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)